# What is the difference between adding stylesheets to javafx.scene.Scene vs view javafx.scene.Parent?

Tags: javafx

I am trying to determine what difference it makes to add stylesheets to
javafx.scene.Scene vs view javafx.scene.Parent.

Is there a difference in use-case or?

Comment: Just the obvious: if you add the stylesheet to the scene, and later change the root of the scene, then the style will apply to the new root. If you add the stylesheet to the root, and change the root, then the style will no longer apply.

Comment: [This documentation](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/15/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#introstylesheets) may be helpful (though it doesn't seem to mention [this](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/15/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/layout/Region.html#getUserAgentStylesheet())). Also, in addition to what @James_D mentions, stylesheets added to a `Scene` are automatically applied to child windows, or at least child dialogs (e.g. `dialog.initOwner(window)`). But I don't know if that's documented anywhere or just an implementation detail.

Comment: I actually did not know that about it being applied to child windows. Thanks for adding in that information. @Slaw